# register events in the ASP.NET API function

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a library of APIs in .NET connects to the server with the event registration of adding or updating sheet.
I want to connect it with the REST API, I created a ASP.NET Web API where I run the server connection and the registration for events.

The function looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
     Clr con = ConnectToServer(value)
     clr.UserAdded += (sender, record) =>
     {

     };
}
```

the question:
Is this an appropriate way, to register events in the API function, or should split it somewhere else, and how? Standard desktop software on the VPS server?

Thanks